# Upgrade to FontAwesome Pro in ASP.NET Zero (Angular) / fas far icons displaying as squares

Tags: asp.net, angular, font-awesome, aspnetboilerplate, zero

I was asked to upgrade an ASP.NET Zero project with the Font Awesome Pro icons.

I followed the steps here [Installing the Pro version of Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/using-package-managers)

After adding the below in the `angular.json`

`"node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/css/all.min.css"`

I found that some of the pro fonts did not want to display specifically some of the solid(`fas`) and regular (`far`) fonts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the issue remove the vendor included Font Awesome Free css from the `src\assets\metronic\vendors\global\vendors.bundle.css` file

[image]

Be sure to remove the trailing comment on line 15 as well

[image]

After the above step be sure to replace all the instances of `Font Awesome 5 Free` with `Font Awesome 5 Pro` especially where they are referenced in .css files

**Please Note that I found some SVG files that contains the phrase 'Font Awesome 5 Free' which I think should remain there**